# ElementHandle.$eval pageFunction not executed

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am parsing a html table using Puppeteer version 1.6.0

```
// inside the rowMarket variable I store all the rows of a table
rowMarket = await.page.$$('#searchTextResults > tbody > tr');
```

Now I want to iterate over all of them, and get the text of some td columns for each row.

If I use the following code everthing works OK.

```
for(i=0<rowMarket.length;i++){
  nameComponent = await rowMarket[i].$('td:nth-child(1) > a');
  iT = await nameComponent .getProperty('innerText');
  json = await iT.jsonValue();

  otherComponent = await rowMarket[i].$(' ... ');
  // ... I repeat the same stuff for every column.
}
```

To reuse some code and not copy & paste a lot I have defined the next function

```
async function getContent(element){
  innerText = await element.getProperty('innerText');
  json = await innerText.jsonValue();
  return json;  
}
```

So I can refactor the previus code in this way

```
for(i=0<rowMarket.length;i++){
  nameComponent = await rowMarket[i].$('td:nth-child(1) > a');
  nameText = getContent(nameComponent);

  otherComponent = await rowMarket[i].$(' ... ');
  otherText = getContent(otherComponent);

  // ...
}
```

But digging into the documentation I came across the [$eval function](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.5.0&show=api-elementhandleevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) which seems to be a fantastic mix for what I was trying to do by hand.

I refactor my code the next way. I think it is pretty clean and compact.

```
for(i=0<rowMarket.length;i++){
  nameText = await rowMarket[i].$eval('td:nth-child(1) > a', getContent);
  otherText = await rowMarket[i].$eval(' ...', getContent);
  // ...
}
```

But I am getting the next error

```
(node:8056) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: elemento.getProperty is not a function
    at dentroElemento (__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2:30)
    at ExecutionContext.evaluateHandle (c:\webscraping\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:97:13)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

I really do not understand the error as the function works OK if called in "standalone" mode.

I have also try this

```
for(i=0<rowMarket.length;i++){
  nameText = await rowMarket[i].$eval('td:nth-child(1) > a', e => console.log('hello?'));
}
```

But the hello String is never log into the console. So I think the problem is the pageFunction function not being called. Or maybe I am doing something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: `await rowMarket[i].$('td:nth-child(1) > a');` returns an **elementHandle**. An elementHandle has the function `.getProperty()`.
So, that is why your first code is working:

```
async function getContent(elementHandle){
  innerText = await elementHandle.getProperty('innerText');
  ...
```

But `.$eval` passes an **Element** as the first argument to your function. And that is not the same as an **elementHandle**.

If you want to do this: `nameText = await rowMarket[i].$eval('td:nth-child(1) > a', getContent);`
Then you should rewrite your *getContent* function to work on an Element like this (because an **Element** does not have the `.getProperty()` function):

```
async function getContent(element){
  innerText = await element.innerText;
```

Comment: It works. I have also notice (I do not know why), the console log statements inside that function are not logged. That made me thought the function was not even called even when using `nameText = await rowMarket[i].$eval('td:nth-child(1) > a', e => console.log('hello?'));`